# generics, not applicable argument for List<integer> when method argument is ( List<? extends T)

Tags: java, generics, syntax-error

I get an error on eclipse  when calling the method maximum, saying the method `maximum (<? extends T>, int, int) in the type generics classname is not applicable for the argument (List<Integer>, int ,int).`
how can i solve this error

```
public class Generics_oracle_question {
        public static void main(String args[]) {
            List<Integer>[] integer = new List[5];
            integer[0].add(6);
            integer[1].add(3);
            integer[2].add(9);
            System.out.println(maximum(integer,0,2));
          }
           public static<T extends Comparable> T maximum(List<? extends T> elements,int beg, int end) {
            T max = elements.get(beg);
            for(; beg <= end; beg++) {
                if(max.compareTo(elements.get(beg)) < 0) {
                    max = elements.get(beg);
                }
            }
            return max;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are passing an array of lists to a method that takes a list.

Here is how you instantiate and populate a `List<Integer>`:

```
List<Integer> integer = new ArrayList<>();
integer.add(6);
integer.add(3);
integer.add(9);
```

Now your code compiles and runs, correctly returning 9 ([demo](https://ideone.com/rEMu5S)).